# Do a calculation in SQL query or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlperformance

this is my first post, so I hope I follow all the conventions :D

I have a MySql database with x and y coordinates and a php web service that receives other x and y coords. I want to calculate the square distance: (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 and sort from closest to farthest

SQL query (in php) would be:

`SELECT ((x_coor-$x)*(x_coor-$x)+(y_coor-$y)*(y_coor-$y)) AS SquareDis FROM $table ORDER BY SquareDis`

What is more gentle to performance, doing this in a SQL query or in the php program?

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Comment: what do you want to do with the result of your query? Are you storing the results in the database or the coordinates in the db will be always the same?

Comment: for easy code reading and troubleshooting I would just grab the coords from database and do the calculation in PHP. This also removes the double calculation you are performing now.

Comment: thanks for the fast replies! the coordinates in the db are changing. with the result I want to figure out who is closest and who is farthest.

Comment: I'd say it's a design choice - @RST has a good point, you can make it really clear with comments as to what you're doing with the data in PHP.

That said, providing your columns are correctly indexed, I'd be tempted to leave the calculation in the SQL as (personally) - I prefer the database to do this sort of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort by the results, then do the calculation in SQL.

Otherwise, you are just using the database as a "file store" and not taking advantage of the functionality that it offers.  In addition, by doing the ordering in the database, you can limit the number of rows being returned -- another optimization.